# Intersection points of three cosine (or sine) functions?

Tags: trigonometry

My question is expanding another question, but because i do not have 50 reputations i could not use the "comment" section for that question. So i make my own question.
The initial question was about find a solution type for x values (values on horizontal axis (time)), of intersection points of two cos functions $\cos(\omega_1t),\cos(\omega_2t)$ with periods $T_1, T_2.$
The solution given in initial question is

$$t=\frac{2\pi n}{\omega_1\pm\omega_2}=\frac{nT_1T_2}{T_2\pm T_1}.$$

My questions are :

1. what will be the type $$t=\frac{nT_1T_2}{T_2\pm T_1}.$$ if instead of two, we have three functions :
   $\cos(\omega_1t),\cos(\omega_2t),\cos(\omega_3t)$, with Periods $T_1,T_2,T_3$
2. if we reverse the problem, the question would be : Find the Periods $T_1,T_2,T_3$, knowing "t" for each "n" ($t_1$ for n=1, $t_2$ for n=2, $t_3$ for n=3...$t_i$ for n=i). Is there a solution to this reversed problem, for the "three functions" case, [probably using the type (if exist such a type) from my first question] ?
3. If instead of "cos" function have "sin" functions, does something changes in solution types ?

Comment: If you are looking for $t$ values, where $\cos(\omega_1 t)=\cos(\omega_2 t)=\cos(\omega_3 t)$, there is not always possible to find such values (except $t=0$). Let mark $t_1=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1+\omega_2}$, $t_2=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1-\omega_2}$, $u_1=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1+\omega_3}$, $u_2=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1-\omega_3}$. Then condition is that some of $\frac{u_i}{t_j}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: No i am not looking for t values, where : cos(ω1t)=cos(ω2t)=cos(ω3t). My main goal is to find Period of each of the three functions, knowing the t values.  In my first question i referred to  the type  $t=\frac{nT_1T_2}{T_2\pm T_1}$ , because this type correlates t with T, and if  t  is known, then we can find T. So, i assume that we know the t values, and i am looking for a type-formula that correlate t with T, in order to calculate T (for each of the three cos functions).

Comment: There is not always possible to find $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ for two cosines. For example, $\omega_1=16$, $\omega_2=8$ and $\omega_1=15$, $\omega_2=9$ give the same set of $t_i$.

Comment: I will rewrite a part of my comment, because i did not mentioned something that may be important. .."My main goal is to find Period of each of the three functions, knowing the t values where the three functions intersect with each other.

Comment: Ivan, i am seeing from your example that  for  $\omega_1$=16 and $\omega_2$=8, AND for  $\omega_1$=15 and  $\omega_2$=9, t=0.2617 for both  couples. Does it means that there are many set of two or three or more cos functions that intersects in the same point in  x-axis but in different point in y-axis (for each set) ?

Comment: But how exactly, this prevent us from find one of those sets.? In my case, a set of three functions (cos or sin). If the question is "find the Period of each of three functions of ANY set of three cos (or sin) functions, whose its functions intersect in $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$, etc, would change something ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{t|\cos(\omega_1 t)=\cos(\omega_2 t)\}$ at some $\omega_1 > \omega_2 > 0$. Let $T_{12}=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1+\omega2}$, $\tau_{12}=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1-\omega2}$, $B=\{iT_{12}|i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, $C=\{k\tau_{12}|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. One can easily show that $A=B\cup C$. Also one can easily show that $T_{12}$ is minimum positive element of $A$.
Then we can restore $B$ from $A$.

There are two possible cases: 1. $\tau_{12}\in B$. 2. $\tau_{12}\notin B$. In first case $C\subset B$ and $A=B$.  In second case $A\ne B$. This is how these cases can be distinguished.

So if $B=A$, then $\tau_{12}=iT_{12}$, $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $i>1$. Any $i$ makes no difference in $A$, so there is an infinite set of possible values $\tau_{12}$. If $B\ne A$, then the only value of $\tau_{12}$ is minimum positive element of $A\setminus B$.

$\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ can be restored from $T_{12}$ and $\tau_{12}$. In first case there is an infinite set of solutions, in second case solution is unique.

For three cosines one can consider $T_{12}$, $\tau_{12}$, $T_{13}$, $\tau_{13}$, $B$, $C$, $D=\{m T_{13}|m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, $E=\{n \tau_{13}|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then $A=(B\cup C)\cap(D\cup E)=$ $(B\cap D)\cup (C\cap D)\cup(B\cap E)\cup(C\cap E)$. The resulting set $A$ can be empty or formed by uniting from 1 to 4 arithmetic progressions. There is too many cases to describe them all. I believe one can develop algorithm to solve the problem. One can start from representing set $A$ (if not empty) as union of arithmetic progressions.